# Why upcasted ab.a + ab.b produce result 1 and 1.0?

Tags: java, downcast, upcasting

I don't get how we managed to invoke constructor without parameters in class `A` at all. 
How upcasting works in this particular example? When we produce `A ab = bb;` what exactly `ab` refers to?

```
public class A {
    public Integer a;
    public Float b;

    public A() {
        a = 1;
        b = 1.0f;
    }

    public A(Integer x) {
        a = 2;
        b = 2.0f;
    }

    public int f(long x) {
        return 3;
    }

    public int f(double x) {
        return 4;
    }

}
```

```
public class B extends A {
    public int a;

    public B(float x) {
        a = 5;
    }

    public int f(int x) {
        return 6;
    }

    public int f(float x) {
        return 7;
    }

    public int f(double x) {
        return 8;
    }

}
```

```
public class M {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A aa = new A(1);
        System.out.println(aa.a + " " + aa.b);// OUT: [ 2 ] [2.0]

        int ret = aa.f(aa.b);
        System.out.println(ret); // OUT: [ 4 ]

        B bb = new B(6);
        A ab = bb;
        System.out.println(bb.a); // OUT: [ 5 ]
        System.out.println(ab.a + " " + ab.b);// OUT: [ 1 ] [1.0]

        ret = bb.f(1);
        System.out.println(ret); // OUT: [ 6 ]

        ret = ab.f(1.0f);
        System.out.println(ret); // OUT: [ 8 ]

        ret = ab.f(aa.a);
        System.out.println(ret); // OUT: [ 3 ]

        ret = bb.f(aa.b);
        System.out.println(ret); // OUT: [ 7 ]

    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: better to use primitive types rather than their reference wrapper counterparts unless you have a good reason for doing so. So use `int` rather than `Integer` and use `float` rather than `Float`, again, unless you have a decent reason for doing so (you don't here).

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels. How did we manage to get results 1 and 1.0 from constructor in class A? How ab.a is equal to 1? Those values are only available through constructor but did we call it?

Comment: Fields are not overridden. And the default constructor *is* called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we produce `A ab = bb;` what exactly `ab` refers to?

It references `bb`, but as an `A`, i.e. one can only call methods and attributes defined in `A`. There is no new object constructed. You can see this by checking `System.out.println(bb == ab);`, which will evaluate as `true`. This concept is known as [attribute- or field-hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html).

This also is the reason why `ab.a` returns `1`, because the attribute `a` (of type `Integer`) within `A` is accessed. If one would, on the other hand, access `bb.a`, one would get the attribute `a` (ob type `int`) within `B`, which is initialzed to be `5`. Keep in mind that, if you construct a `B`, there is always an explicit or implicit call to a superclass constructor as defined in [JLS, §12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

Comment: can you please explain why  result ab.a was equal 1?

Comment: Because with `ab.a`, you access `A`'s attribute `a` (the `Integer`), which was initialzed with `1`. If you access `bb.a`, you access `B`'s attribute `a` (the `int`), which is initialized with `5`. This is known as [attribute hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) and is a mechanism within Java's inheritance model.